# Why does my form submit, when ignoring the popup alert

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form where no fields can be empty. I popup an alert box when user tries to submit the form with empty fields. but when user clicks on ok in the alert box the form get submitted.

Below is my code:

js:

```
 function checkIt(f)
  {   
    if (f.elements['username'].value=="" && f.elements['text'].value=="") {      
        alert('Both fields are required');
        return false;   
    } else {
        return true;
    } 
  }
```

form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return checkIt(this)" id="submit">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <label>Enter Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <label>Enter Your Text</label>

<input type="submit" value="Submit Comment"/>
</form>
```

Action code:

```
$('.submit').submit(function(){

          $.ajax({
              url : ....,
              data : $(' form').serialize(),
              type: "POST",
              success : function(){
              }
          })

          return false;
      })
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: to prevent a form being submitted i use event.preventDefault see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: Your test will only fail if both inputs are empty. If only one of them is filled it will treat it as OK.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, there isn't enough detail in your question to reproduce it. [When I tried](http://jsbin.com/aputut/1/edit) the script stopped the form from submitting. (Voting to close as Not A Real Question)

Comment: @Quentin I have added the full form. I don't know what else code is needed to check a form validation

Comment: @ehp — None, [that code](http://jsbin.com/ejexas/1/edit) works.

Comment: @ehp — Your `label` elements are not associated with your `input` elements. Either put the inputs inside the labels, or add `for="ID-of-input"` to the labels.

Comment: @ehp then where does it get posted ? some other code is running to which you are referring as the data gets submitted ?

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong. The form should not submit if the validation fails. If it does submit, then I would suspect one of three things; (a) that `checkIt()` is not in scope, (b) that another `checkIt()` function overwrites this one, or (c) that the form is nested inside another form, which is invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I have added action code as well. Hopes it will help to find the problem

Comment: Hang on, now you've added the bit about "Action code:". It would have been nice to know about that before as it renders `checkIt()` redundant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which works for me

```
 $('.submitComment').submit(function(){
      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

      if (username != "" && text != "") {
          $.ajax({
              url : 
              data : $(' form').serialize(),
              type: "POST",
              success : function(){
              }
          })  
      } else {
          alert('Both fields are required');
      }

      return false;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (f.elements['username'].value=="" && f.elements['text'].value=="") {
```

Because form submission prevents only if BOTH fields are empty. You should use OR(||) instrad of AND(&&)

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem though (it solves a **different** problem that the code has). The question says the alert box comes up and then the form submits anyway (so the if condition can't be the cause).